# openJDK version numbers - Are these macros?: $MAJOR.$MINOR.$SECURITY. How are these accessed?

Tags: java, macros, version, versioning

At [this link](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/223) there is discussion of version numbers. There is no explanation there, or anywhere else I found, of what these macro-looking things are. For example, in what context is "$VNUM" used? What is its scope? Is it defined in a C++ header file used during openJDK compilation? Is it accessible from within my java program? Is it some kind of environment variable?

Thank you for any explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$` followed by a name is a standard way to make use of variables in Unix shell scripts and command line prompts.  The JEP to which you’ve linked is not actually referring to a Unix command, but rather is using that syntax to indicate how certain values are arranged.

If you open a terminal right now in Linux or OS X, you can enter something like this to see how the variable replacement works:

```sh
MAJOR=11
MINOR=0
SECURITY=3
echo $MAJOR.$MINOR.$SECURITY
```

The author could have described it using Java syntax, like `major + "." + minor + "." + security`, or could have described it with a BNF-like notation, but chose to do it this way instead.

The version elements are used by instances of the [Runtime.Version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.Version.html) class.  You can obtain an instance for the currently running JVM using the [Runtime.version()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#version%28%29) method.

Why would you want to look at it?  To work around known bugs in a particular version, or to make use of newer APIs when available.

If you wanted to get the value that the JEP describes as `$VNUM`, you would write:

```
String vnum = Runtime.version().version().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(
    Collectors.joining("."));
```

…which concatenates the major/minor/security numbers (which actually are not called that anymore) with a period in between.

Usually, however, you won’t need that string.  You’re more likely to compare the version, to test for a particular bug or capability:

```
Runtime.Version requiredVersion = Runtime.Version.parse("11");

if (Runtime.version().compareTo(requiredVersion) < 0) {
    System.err.println("This program requires Java 11 or later.");
    System.exit(1);
}
```